# Listener to items in choice

Tags: java, applet

I am working with java applets inorder to embed this applet into one web page. In this applet i used a Choice class to show dropdown list. I know **ItemListener** helps to know which item is selected once we select an item but Is this possible to know which item has the foucs currently??. i.e, i used the following code

```
choice = new Choice();
choice.addItem("");
choice.addItem("Choice1");
choice.addItem("Choice 2");
choice.addItem("Choice 3");
```

Now if i place cursor on choice2 instead of click on it,it has to perform some action. What are the ways to do this?

Comment: What is the relevance of performing some action on item 'highlight'?  This is not the way the user would expect a `Choice` or `JComboBox` to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to [add an ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html#addItemListener%28java.awt.event.ItemListener%29). After you do that, the item listener will be called when something is selected by user input, and then you can take the appropriate action.

One question though, is there a particular reason you're using awt instead of swing?

Comment: Only reason iam using applet is to embed it into web page.and If i use ItemListener and overrides ItemStateChanged() it will be invoked only when i select an item.But i want to know which item is currently pointing(focused)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29 will work, and there are several others documented there.

Comment: *"Only reason iam using applet is to embed it into web page."*  Swing includes [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) which can also be embedded in a web page.  But a better strategy is to use a Swing based `JFrame` and launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Please start comments to me with @Andrew so I am notified.  Why a `JApplet` and not a JWS launched `JFrame`?  What does being embedded in a browser window actually do for the app.?  Note that I also asked you another question you seem to have ignored.  Please do not mistake SO for a help-desk.  Either answer questions I ask, or find someone else to help.